# Query that references enum in joined Rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, rails-activerecord

Consider the following simplified representation of my domain model.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  enum :value, %i{hot cold}

  validates :value, uniqueness: { scope: :item_id }
end
```

Every item has zero or more tags which indicate properties of the item that may be relevant to my program. In this example, "hot" and "cold" are the only valid tags.

If I want to find all of the items which are tagged as "hot", I can write

```
Item.joins(:tags).where('tags.value = 0')
```

Naturally, I'd prefer to write the word "hot" instead of the enum's integer value. I can sort of force ActiveRecord's hand with a named argument.

```
Item.joins(:tags).where('tags.value': 'hot')
```

But having a named argument whose name is not a valid Ruby identifier feels sort of... wrong. Is there a neater way to make this query, that doesn't involve such a bizarre pseudo-variable?

Comment: is it `'tags.value'` that you find so bizarre?

Comment: Yes, I'm not fond of the named argument (which, in my head, I'm treating as a variable name) not being a valid identifier and requiring quotes.

Comment: It is Ruby [symbol](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbol+Literals) with quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this feel better:

```rb
Item.joins(:tags).where(tags: {value: :hot})
```

or

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags

  scope :tagged, ->(value) { joins(:tags).where(tags: {value:}) }
end

Item.tagged(:hot)
```

Comment: Small note: hash `{value:}` will work in Ruby 3.1+

Answer (score 2):

Firstly code in the question is wrong. If item has many tags you need to use this association name. `joins(:tags)`, not `joins(:tag)`. Otherwise error will raise

Usually for joined tables in `where` method hash is used. Key is the table name, value is the hash with necessary arguments

```rb
Item.joins(:tags).where(tags: { value: 'hot' })
```

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the note on the `joins`. That was a copy-paste error not present in my real code. Thanks for the suggestion! I'm accepting Alex's answer because of the helpful note on scopes, but know your help is appreciated as well :)